# Excel Formula Queries for Solutions

Tags: excel

I have a huge set of excel data which has text in the month column horizontally. And i have these text column horizontally as well. Now i need to replace the text with value 1 which matches horizontally as well.

Ex:

```
A                 B                 c           D                 E            F
Sale          Sale+ Financing       Pack    Reduced pricing   Accessories   Demonstrator
Servicing
Financing
Accessories
Demonstrator
Pack
Reduced Pricing
```

Would be immensely grateful to achieve co-operation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is stored in the following structure, the equation for B2 is `=IF($A2=$B1,"match","")`. Drag this equation to cover the range B2:H8.

```
  |-----A---------|---B----|----C------|---D---|---E-----|----F------|-------G-------|-------H-------|
1 |                 Sale    Financing    Pack    Reduced    pricing    Accessories    Demonstrator
2 | Sale            match                        
3 | Servicing
4 | Financing               match
5 | Accessories                                                        match
6 | Demonstrator                                                                      match
7 | Pack                                 match
8 | Reduced                                      match
```